# How to remove gap between banner slider and home page?

Tags: magento-1.9, php

### How to remove the gap between Banner slider and CMS home page (Magento 1.9) ?

I have installed `Magestore Banner slider.`

But by default, It is keeping space between Slider and my `CMS home page`.

Please suggest a solution to remove this space, And to join `CMS home page` and `Banner slider`.

Comment: check the css which create this gape and try to remove that.

Comment: please update question with site url if possible.....

Comment: How can someone give answer of this question ?